# Html code for mobile version Now needs to be converted into Desktop version so its used for both Mobile and Desktop

Tags: html, css, mobile, desktop-application, desktop

Right now code is mobile friendly because of the way I have it setup now I just want it to be desktop friendly without messing up the mobile version.

Here is what i have so far and css in the bottom .......

```
@model IEnumerable<GSWebAPI.GS_Survey_Questions>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layout_Surveys.cshtml";
    int counter = 0;
}

@foreach (var i in Model)
{

    if (i.Question_Type == "DROPDOWN")
    {

        <div class="container text-center">


                <div class="row idrow" data-questions="@counter">
                    @{counter++;
                    }

                        <div id="question1" class="form-group">
                            <label class="lab text-center" for="form-group-select">
                                @i.Question_Order @Html.Raw(@i.Question)
                            </label>
                            @{ var works = "question" + counter.ToString();}
                            <select name="@works" class="form-control selects" id="form-group-select">
                                @for (int x = 1; x <= Convert.ToInt32(i.Question_SubType); x++)
                                    {
                                        var t = x - 1;
                                        if (i.qOps != null)
                                        {
                                        <option> @i.qOps.options[t]</option>
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                        <option> @x</option>

                                        }
                                    }
                            </select>
                        </div>







                </div>

        </div>

                        }

                        if (i.Question_Type == "RADIO")
                        {




        <div class="container">
            <div class="row idrow" data-questions="@counter">
                @{counter++;
                }
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="lab" for="questions">
                       @i.Question_Order @i.Question
                    </label>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div id="question1" class="radio-inline">
                                @for (int x = 1; x <= Convert.ToInt32(i.Question_SubType); x++)
                                {
                                    var t = x - 1;
                                    if (i.qOps != null)
                                    {
                                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="question"> @i.qOps.options[t]</label>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {

                                          <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" min="0" max="@x" name="question"></label>

                                    }
                                }
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>

    }
    if (i.Question_Type == "CHECKBOX")
    {
        for (int y = 1; y <= Convert.ToInt32(i.Question_SubType); y++)
        {
            @*<div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <label>@y</label>   <input type="checkbox" name="question">

                </div>
            </div>*@
        }
    }

}
<div class="azibsButtons">
    <button type="button" id="previous"  class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Prev</button>

    <button type="button" id="next"  class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Next</button>

    <button type="button" id="submit" onclick="Sendingitoff();" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit</button>
</div>



<script>
    function formToJSON() {
        var form = {};
        $('.selects').each(function () {
            var self = $(this);
            var name = self.attr('name');
            if (form[name]) {
                form[name] = form[name] + ',' + self.val();
            }
            else {
                form[name] = self.val();
            }
        });

        return form;
    }



    function Sendingitoff(){
        debugger;
        var form = formToJSON();
        var look = JSON.stringify(form);

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Answers", "GSSurvey")/' + '?username=@Request.QueryString["username"]'  + '&receiverid=@Request.QueryString["receiverid"]' + '&id=@Request.QueryString["id"]',

            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: look,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {



            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            }
        });

    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ShowTheelement(0);
        $("#previous").addClass('hidden');
        $("#submit").addClass('hidden');

        var dataVal = 0;

        $("#next").click(function () {
            dataVal++;
            $("#previous").removeClass('hidden');
            dataVal == $(".idrow[data-questions]").length-1 ? $(this).addClass('hidden') : $(this).removeClass('hidden');
            ShowTheelement(dataVal);
            if (dataVal == $(".idrow[data-questions]").length - 1)
                $("#submit").removeClass('hidden');
        });

        $("#previous").click(function () {
            dataVal--;
            $("#next").removeClass('hidden');
            dataVal == 0 ? $(this).addClass('hidden') : $(this).removeClass('hidden');
            ShowTheelement(dataVal);
            if (dataVal == $(".idrow[data-questions]").length - 2)
                $("#submit").addClass('hidden');

        });
    });

    function ShowTheelement(dataVal) {
        $(".idrow").addClass('hidden');
        $(".idrow[data-questions='" + dataVal + "']").removeClass('hidden');
    }
</script>

.navbar-header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 19%;
    top: 10%

}
/* Portrait */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1025px) and (max-device-width: 1200px) {

    .form-control {
        margin-right: 25%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {

    .form-control {
        margin-left: 13%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 412px) {

    .form-control {
        margin-left: 11%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 370px) {

    .form-control {
        margin-left: 2%;
    }
}


.azibsButtons {

    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.form-control {
    margin-top: 15px;
     position: fixed;
     top:250px;
}
.idrow label{
      height:100px;
     max-height: 100px;
     min-height:100px;

}
.form-group{
    max-height:188px;
    min-height:188px;
}
.lab {
    font-size: 13px;

}

.form-control-select {

}

.form-group {
    margin-top: 20px;  

}
.body-content {
    margin-top: 110px;

}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    padding: 8px 90px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

    a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
    }


.body-content .row {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.navbar {
    height: 150px;
}

#navbar-wrapper .imgLogo {
    width: 200px;
}

#surveryForm .form-group {
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#surveryForm .radio-inline2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}



#surveryForm .radio-inline3 {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#surveryForm .radio-inline {
    font-size: 15px;
}

#surveryForm .form-group .checkbox-inline {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Can I take this code and just add on a div wrapped all over it?

Comment: What frameworks/libraries are you using?

Comment: I am using MVC .net framework @liroP

Comment: Please Google _**responsive web design**_. And please don't copy-and-paste your mobile content for desktop. Besides, it looks like you're using Twitter Bootstrap which is great for building responsive websites.

Comment: @hungerstar is right. Check https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/ and learn about grids and responsive design. Resize your window to see efect mobile/desktop and viceverse.

Comment: @hungerstar how does it work? just feeds you information on how to do thing?

Comment: i already have my mobile setup now working on desktop

Comment: Not sure which version you're using but review the documentation, it's all there; [**Bootstrap 3 Documentation**](http://getbootstrap.com/) - [**Bootstrap 4 Documentation**](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this question on my own, down below is what I coded...

//@media only screen is pointing towards what sizes you can imagine this webpage will be displayed on, you may also write your CSS measurement according to the size of the device  //

//desktop --//

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 760px) and (max-device-width: 3000px)  {
    .navbar-header{
       position: absolute;
         left: 45%;
    }
    hr {
    display: block;
    background-color:blue;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 8%;
}
    .azibsButtons {

    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
    .form-control {
        margin-left: 40%;
    }
}
```

// iphone 6 plus --//

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {

    .form-control {
        margin-left: 13%;
    }
    hr {
    display: block;
    background-color:blue;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 35%;
}
}

//iphone 6 --//

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 412px) {

    .form-control {
        margin-left: 11%;
    }
    hr {
    display: block;
    background-color:blue;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 39%;
}
}
//iphone 5 --//

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 370px) {

    .form-control {
        margin-left: 2%;
    }
    hr {
    display: block;
    background-color:blue;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 46%;
}
}
```